# Inheritance and modules in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this structure:

```
class1 < class2
```

A simple child < parent relationship.

I got a module, module1.

file CLASS_1.rb:

```
class1 < class2

end
```

file CLASS_2.rb:

```
class2
  include module1
end
```

file MODULE_1.rb:

```
module module1

end
```

why do I get this:

```
'<class:class2>': uninitialized constant class2::module1 (NameError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class/module names should be constants (that is, begin with a capital letter).

```
class Class1 < Class2
  include Module1
end
```

And also don't forget to require corresponding files.

```
# class1.rb
require_relative 'class2'
require_relative 'module1'

class Class1 < Class2
  include Module1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`module1` has to be created by the time it is included. If you have not loaded or required MODULE_1.rb before `class2` definition/creation in CLASS_2.rb, then `module1` is not created at its inclusion to `class2`.